# GNU linker marking section with no initialized data for LOAD - Raw binary huge

Tags: linker, gnu, ld, linker-scripts

I'm writing a bare metal ARM boot loader and am trying to use some internal SRAM as a scratch pad to communicate to the application code.  For my needs I don't need to initialise or zero the memory.  Using this script I can place my desired variables in the memory just fine.

```
/**
 * Linker script for secondary bootloader.
 *
 * Allocatest the first 1Mb of DRAM for its use.
 * Scratchpad in internal SRAM.
 */

MEMORY
{
    SRAM : o = 0x402F0400, l = 0x0000FC00  /* 63kB available internal SRAM */
    DDR0 : o = 0x80000000, l = 1M          /* 1Mb external DDR Bank 0 */
}

OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm")
OUTPUT_ARCH(arm)

SECTIONS
{
    .startcode :
    {
        __AppBase = .;
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *init.o      (.text)
    } >DDR0

    .text :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.text*)
        *(.rodata*)
    } >DDR0

    .data :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.data*)
    } >DDR0

    .bss :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _bss_start = .;
        *(.bss*)
        *(COMMON)
        _bss_end = .;
    } >DDR0

    .stack :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __StackLimit = . ;
        *(.stack*)
        . = __AppBase + 1M;
        __StackTop = .;
    } >DDR0
    _stack = __StackTop;

    .internal_ram :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.internal_ram*)
    } >SRAM
}
```

When using objcopy to create the raw binary, I'm getting huge files.  I'm assuming this is because the first bytes of the raw binary are actually the internal memory with megabytes of padding up to the start of the .text section.  Objdump -h shows that the internal_ram section being marked with the CONTENTS, LOAD, and DATA flags even though the variables placed there are not initialised.

I can clean this up in objcopy using --remove-section=.internal_ram but it seems there should be a way to get the linker to recognise that the data is not initialised.

Is there a way to mark the section appropriately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct section declaration is:

```
.internal_ram (NOLOAD) :
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.internal_ram*)
} >SRAM
```

The NOLOAD section attribute is documented but speaks in terms of program loaders handling the section at load time.  At first this doesn't seem to apply to bare metal images but, for that purpose, objcopy acts like a program loader and honors the flag settings in the object file, omitting the section from the raw image.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer mentions this as well - the key is to make the section *NOLOAD* so that the data remains uninitialized.

> The `(NOLOAD)’ directive will mark a section to not be loaded at run time. The linker will process the section normally, but will mark it so that a program loader will not load it into memory.

A quote from [Ashley Duncan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57181652/understanding-linker-script-noload-sections-in-embedded-software#comment105830048_57182365) that you might find useful:

> NOLOAD is useful in embedded projects for making sure a block of RAM is not initialised or zeroed. For example if you want the contents of that RAM to not lose its values during a software reset (e.g. if you want to set a variable with the reason you are resetting). Another useful application is to pass information from a boot loader to application without the application startup code overwriting the values of that memory area. Of course in this case both the boot loader and application linker files need to declare the exact same memory area location and size.

Some more explanation/story can be found [here](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2014/04/19/gnu-linker-can-you-not-initialize-my-variable/)