# Understanding linker script NOLOAD sections in embedded software

Tags: memory, linker, embedded, loader, firmware

According to the GNU documentation for `ld`, a `NOLOAD` section works as following:

> The `(NOLOAD)' directive will mark a section to not be loaded at run
> time. The linker will process the section normally, but will mark it
> so that a program loader will not load it into memory.

Now, regarding to the *program loader*, accordign to wikipedia:

> Embedded systems typically do not have loaders, and instead, the code
> executes directly from ROM. In order to load the operating system
> itself, as part of booting, a specialized boot loader is used.

**Then, what exactly a `NOLOAD` section does for FW / embedded software?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done several experiments, so I will add an answer in the specific context of embedded software, in particular in absence of loaders (included flash tools with such functionality). This is my understanding after the experiments I have done, but if anything is wrong I will be more than happy to edit the answer.

It's true that `NOLOAD` will mark a section so that 'the loader' knows that it must not load it into memory. Something similar will happen for flashing tools that receive an `.elf` file as an input, therefore, to some extent, act as loaders.

However, there are many cases in embedded software in which a loader is not present, for instance if the target device allows to update the firmware only with raw binary files, and it just copies the raw data at a particular address and nothing else. In this cases, `NOLOAD` will be useful to avoid making the raw binary file unnecessarily big: it will prevent a section to be added to the final binary file when it's not desirable.

Use cases in which it would not be desirable:

- If the section in question needs to be initialized to a known value, such as 0x0, 0xff, or some magic number and then all 0x0 etc. Therefore it's not worth to have a (potentially) big section full of 0xff's, when this can be done in a loop at the startup script.
- If that particular area of memory must not be overwritten during the update process. Beware of this will require to place that section at a particular position. See below.
- If the section contains non-initialized data, such as `.bss`, but it's not `.bss`, in which case `NOLOAD` will need to be set explicitly. Of course, this will need to be initialized to 0 or whatever constant value by the startup script.

Notice that the `NOLOAD` section will still be present in the `.elf` file (it won't be marked as `LOAD` though), but it should be removed by `objcopy` when generating the raw binary file. There is one exception to this though: `objcopy` cannot 'remove' a section in between another two because it needs to keep the memory map somehow. For instance, having sections A B C, `NOLOAD` won't work on B, because `objcopy` will need to fill `B` with zeros to keep the offset of section `C` as expected. However, if `C` is `NOLOAD` and it's the last (potentially loadable) section, then it can be removed from the final binary image.

Another special case I have observed is the `.bss` section. This section is always treated (at least by my version of `riscv64-uknown-elf` toolchain) as `NOLOAD`, regardless if the linker script specifies it or not.

In summary, the uses of `NOLOAD` for embedded systems that do not use a loader are: to keep raw binary images smaller, or to not overwrite memory regions (usually flash) that one wants to leave with the value they had before the firmware update process started.

What `NOLOAD` cannot do if no loader is present, a.k.a. FW is updated as raw binary files, is to avoid a section to be put in a raw binary file if that section is in between another two that do need to be loaded. In such case, all the the `NOLOAD` sections will need to be moved to the end of the loadable memory.

As a side note, for the case of avoiding to overwrite memory, as far as I can see that could be worked out by not declaring that section at all. If symbols in that section need to be referenced from the source code, just declare those symbols at the right addresses.

Answer (score 7):

The `NOLOAD` section defines a section that is required to link the program properly but must not be loaded to memory. For example you may need to link your program with some code located in ROM, so you tell the linker to mark the code in ROM as `NOLOAD`. Then the tool that will load the program (a debugger, an OS or whatever) will not load this part of the code.

Comment: In other words, you mark as NOLOAD those sections you don't want to overwrite when upgrading the FW, right?

Comment: It's more used for ROM (that cannot be written anyway) or RAM (you don't want the loader to initialise RAM for some reason).

Comment: `NOLOAD` sections will not be part of the resulting binary image of your application that the linker generates.

Comment: NOLOAD is useful in embedded projects for making sure a block of RAM is not initialised or zeroed.  For example if you want the contents of that RAM to not lose its values during a software reset (e.g. if you want to set a variable with the reason you are resetting).  Another useful application is to pass information from a boot loader to application without the application startup code overwriting the values of that memory area.  Of course in this case both the boot loader and application linker files need to declare the exact same memory area location and size.

Comment: I'm marking some sections as `NOLOAD`, but they still show up as loadable segments. I've asked this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65848013/6271889)

Comment: Typically BSS sections are marked NOLOAD. (variables initialized with zero). They don't have to be loaded to save time (but takes space in memory) and usually during the start up the program writes the section with zero.